# Question about cost function for logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

During a lecture on logistic regression in coursera, there was a question about the cost function as shown in the following images:
[image]
[image]

I don't understand why the third unselected option is true?

Comment: The given answer is not correct. It should be $0$ instead of  $\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logistic regression, $h_\theta(x)=\frac{1}{1 + e^{-\theta^{T}x}}$ is the sigmoidal function. So, $-\log(1 - h_\theta(x))$ = $-\log{\frac{1}{1 + e^{\theta^{T}{x}}}}$. So, if
$h_\theta(x)$ tends to $0$ then $e^{\theta^{T}x} = 0$, So, the cost should be $0$ should not be $-\infty$, which makes sense since the cost should be minimum for correct prediction where $h_\theta(x)$ matches the actual $y$ value.